# What is wrong with the rotation of this 3d camera I made on CodeSculptor3, a browser-based Python interpreter with a GUI?

Tags: python, graphics, rotation, linear-algebra, projection

Here is the link to the codes and you can play around with the program:
https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user306_KJotPenLg75Fx0e_6.py

```
import simplegui
import math
import codeskulptor

width,height=800,550
center=(width/2,height/2)
keys=0
pi=3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#Camera
cam_pos=[0,0,0] 
cam_speed=5
rotate_speed=pi/90#radians
yaw,pitch=0,0
W,R,A,S,D,F,DOWN,UP,LEFT,RIGHT=False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False
#The distance between the camera and the canvas. 
canvas_distance=400  
#input a 3d point, return the projected position on the canvas                           
def projection(pos):   
    delta_x=-pos[0]
    delta_y=-pos[1]
    delta_z=-pos[2]
    if delta_z==canvas_distance:return(center[0]-delta_x,center[1]+delta_y)
    if 0<delta_z<canvas_distance:return (center[0]-(delta_x/delta_z)*canvas_distance,center[1]+(delta_y/delta_z)*canvas_distance)
    if delta_z<=0:return (center[0]-delta_x*10000,center[1]+delta_y*10000)
    ratio=canvas_distance/delta_z
    return [center[0]-delta_x*ratio,center[1]+delta_y*ratio]

#rotate around the camera
def rotation(pos):
    #yaw changes x and z
    if LEFT==True or RIGHT==True:
        cosine=math.cos(yaw)
        sine=math.sin(yaw)
        pos[2]=cosine*pos[2]+sine*pos[0]
        pos[0]=cosine*pos[0]-sine*pos[2]
    #pitch changes y and z
    elif UP==True or DOWN==True:
        cosine=math.cos(pitch)
        sine=math.sin(pitch)
        pos[1]=cosine*pos[1]+sine*pos[2]
        pos[2]=cosine*pos[2]-sine*pos[1] 
    return pos

def cam_update():
    global yaw,pitch
    if W==True:translate(2,cam_speed)
    elif S==True:translate(2,-cam_speed)  
    if A==True:translate(0,cam_speed)
    elif D==True:translate(0,-cam_speed)  
    if R==True:translate(1,-cam_speed)
    elif F==True:translate(1,+cam_speed)                            
    if LEFT==True or RIGHT==True or UP==True or DOWN==True:    
        if LEFT==True:yaw=rotate_speed
        elif RIGHT==True:yaw=-rotate_speed  
        if UP==True:pitch=rotate_speed
        elif DOWN==True:pitch=-rotate_speed
        rotate()
        
def keyup(key):
    global W,R,A,S,D,F,DOWN,UP,LEFT,RIGHT,keys
    keys-=1
    if  key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['W']:W=False     
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['S']:S=False
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['A']:A=False
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['D']:D=False
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['R']:R=False
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['F']:F=False
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['up']:UP=False
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['down']:DOWN=False
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['left']:LEFT=False
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['right']:RIGHT=False
def keydown(key):
    global W,R,A,S,D,F,DOWN,UP,LEFT,RIGHT,keys
    keys+=1
    #move forward & backward
    if  key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['W']:W,S=True,False     
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['S']:S,W=True,False
    #move left & right
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['A']:A,D=True,False
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['D']:D,A=True,False
    #levitate & fall
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['R']:R,F=True,False
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['F']:F,R=True,False
    #pitch
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['up']:UP,DOWN=True,False
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['down']:DOWN,UP=True,False
    #yaw
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['left']:LEFT,Right=True,False
    elif key==simplegui.KEY_MAP['right']:RIGHT,LEFT=True,False                                                                                
def find_distance(a,b):
    if len(a)==2:return math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2+(a[1]-b[1])**2)
    return math.sqrt((a[0]-b[0])**2+(a[1]-b[1])**2+(a[2]-b[2])**2)
    
class Point:
    def __init__(self,name,color,loc):
        self.name=name
        self.loc=loc#(x,y,z)
        self.color=color
        self.pos=projection(self.loc)#canvas position

#Declaring Point objects
x=Point('X','red',[800,-180,-1300])
y=Point('Y','blue',[-200,820,-1300])
z=Point('Z','green',[-200,-180,-300])
origin=Point('O','white',[-200,-180,-1300])
points=[x,y,z,origin]

#translate all points        
def translate(axis,units):
    for point in points:point.loc[axis]+=units  
#rotate all points
def rotate():
    for point in points:point.loc=rotation(point.loc) 

#this function executes 60 times a second        
def draw(canvas):   
    for point in points:
        canvas.draw_line(origin.pos,point.pos,3,point.color)
        canvas.draw_text(point.name+str([int(x) for x in point.loc]),point.pos,15,'white') 
    
    #if any keys are pressed, update points' locations   
    if keys>0:
        cam_update()
        for point in points:
            point.pos=projection(point.loc)    
    canvas.draw_text('distance between Z and O: '+str(find_distance(z.loc,origin.loc)),[15,20],20,'yellow')
                     
frame = simplegui.create_frame("SSS 3D", width, height)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)
frame.set_keydown_handler(keydown)
frame.set_keyup_handler(keyup)
label=frame.add_label('Click the canvas first')
label=frame.add_label('To move: WASD RF')
label=frame.add_label('To yaw or pitch: arrow keys')
frame.start()
```

When I try to rotate, the distance between two points decreases. You can see that the axes in my example keep shrinking. It also looks like the angles between the axes are getting more and more acute.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Precision problem. I just need to reduce intermediary variables and return the value in one long calculation.